# validating form. addEventListener not listening

Tags: javascript, html

OK so I have a form that I check to see if the user enters in a username in the username field. On top of that i also want to know what button what clicked, really im looking to see when the logout button is clicked. It seems to me that the addEventListener isn't registering the 'click' value when the form is submitted. both the `buttons` and the  `buttonLength` have the right values when I run it with Firefox debugger. So my question is, how do I check the addEventListener value or if its getting passed? looking for some insight on what I'm doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Not empty</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script>

function ValidateForm(frm){

        var buttons = document.getElementsByName('adam');
        var buttonsLength = buttons.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < buttonsLength; i++){
            buttons[i].addEventListener('click', clickResponse, false);
        };

       function clickResponse(){

        if(this.id == "logout"){
            alert(this.id);
        }else {
            alert("not logout:" + this.id); 
        };
    };
    if (!frm.UserName.value) {
                alert("You must enter your username.");
                frm.UserName.focus();
                return false;
            }
          return true;          
}
 </script>
<form method="post" action="test.html" onsubmit="return ValidateForm(this)">
            <input type="input" name="UserName" value="">
            <input type="password" name="Password" value="">
    <button name="adam" id="login">login</button>
    <button name="adam" id="sendMe">send me my password</button>
    <button name="adam" id="logout">logout</button>
<form>
 </body>
```

Comment: You have a capital in username in the JS but not in the html. Another problem that you are going to have is that you are assigning a new instance of the function every time a button is clicked.

Comment: sorry that was my fault from copying and pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong but I think you try to do the following:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <title>Not empty</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <form method="post" name="formname" action="test.html">
    <input type="input" id="username" name="userName" value="">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="Password" value="">
    <button type="button" name="adam" id="login">login</button>
       <button type="button" name="adam" id="sendMe">send me my        password</button>
       <button type="button" name="adam" id="logout">logout</button>
   <form>
    <script>

   var buttons = document.getElementsByName('adam');
   var buttonsLength = buttons.length;

   for(var i=0;i<buttonsLength; i++){
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', clickResponse, false);
   };

   function clickResponse(){
    var u, p;
    u=document.getElementById('username');
    p=document.getElementById('password');
    switch(this.id) {
        case 'logout':
            alert('Logout '+this.id);
            break;
        case 'login':
            if(u.value.length==0 ||
                p.value.length==0) {
                   alert("Please enter your unsername and password.");
                   if(u.length==0) {
                    u.focus();
                   } else {
                    p.focus();
                   }
               } else {
                alert('submit');
                //document.forms.formname.submit();
               }
            break;
        case 'sendMe':
            if(u.value.length==0) {
                   alert("Please enter your username.");
                   u.focus();
                   return false;
               } else {
                alert('submit');
                //document.forms.formname.submit();
               }
            break;
    }
   };

   </script>
   </body>
```

So, you need to assign listeners before click, then I guessed you want to capture click check button id (command to execute) and then check if user and pass are fullfilled depending the button clicked, if so then submit the form... I've changed your code but I think is what you're looking for.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: So when you say assign the Listeners before the click, the JS code has to be after the buttons are created?

Comment: In your code you assign listeners in `onsubmit` event. I've changed that and moved event assigment out of function so have to move script after buttons in DOM. Maybe I complicated understanding but should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help this works great for what i am trying to accomplish. I didn't think about when the listeners is assigned. I just thought it was assigned when you clicked a button no matter where it is called.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little messy and hard to understand exactly what you need.

That being said, you should use `onclick` attributes to bind the buttons to 3 separate functions.

Inside those functions you can get ahold of any dom nodes you need to preform login/logout/sendMe functionality.

Like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Not empty</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

    function login(){
        alert('login function');

        // do what you need to here to login
        var username = document.getElementsByName('input-username').value;
        var password = document.getElementsByName('input-password').value;

        if (!username){
            alert("You must enter your username.");
        }else if (!password){
            alert("You must enter your password.");
        }
    }

    function sendMe(){
        alert('sendMe function');

        // sendMe functionality here
    }

    function logout(){
        alert('logout function');

        // logout functionality here
    }

    </script>
    <form method="post" action="test.html">
        <input id='input-username' type="input" name="UserName" value="" />
        <input id='input-password' type="password" name="Password" value="" />

        <button id="login" onClick="login()">login</button>
        <button id="sendMe" onClick="sendMe()">send me my password</button>
        <button id="logout" onClick="logout()">logout</button>
    <form>
</body>
```